# VBA, If all rows in Col A is filled and Col B is blank(and vice versa) then copy those rows to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to incorporate the following logic, If all rows in Col A is filled and Col B is blank(and vice versa) then copy those rows to a new sheet.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub DataValidation()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rng = Range("A:B")

    For Each cell In rng
        
    If Cel.Value = "" Then
    Sheets("List").Cel.Value.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

Can anyone help with this?
I need help with 1) `If.Cel.Value=""` , I dont think this identifies the logic for Col A filled and Col B is blank. 2) And I need help identifying these rows and copying to a new tab.

Latest code:

```
Sub DataValidationTwo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, rngCopy As Range, i As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = ws.Range("AU4:AV" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration/processing

    For i = 4 To UBound(arr) '4 supposing that headers exist on the third row
        If (arr(i, 1) <> "" And arr(i, 2) = "") Or (arr(i, 2) <> "" And arr(i, 1) = "") Then
            addToRange rngCopy, ws.Range("A" & i)
        End If
    Next i
        
   If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.EntireRow.Copy _
         Sheets("test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
         
    MsgBox "Complete"
End Sub
```

new code. It is only pasting row 4 to test. It should paste more of my test rows over.

```
Sub DataValidationTwo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, rngCopy As Range, i As Long
    
    With Sheets("test")
    .Rows(2 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
    End With
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'Set ws = Sheets("ATP List")
    lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = ws.Range("AU4:AV" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration/processing

    For i = 4 To UBound(arr) '4 supposing that headers exist on the third row
        If (arr(i, 1) <> "" And arr(i, 2) = "") Or (arr(i, 2) <> "" And arr(i, 1) = "") Then
            addToRange rngCopy, ws.Range("A" & i)
        End If
        

    Next i
        
   If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.EntireRow.Copy _
         Sheets("test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
         
         
    MsgBox "Complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: It may be easier to use `Range.AutoFilter` here instead of looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your reference to `cell.value` has a typo, it needs to be `cell.value`

As for the solution, just like Bigben said, a `Range.AutoFilter` is probably the simplest option here without Advanced Filters.

You'll be looking for something like this

```
rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" 'This will filter by non-blanks in Column 1

rng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" 'This will filter by blanks in Column 2
```

When a range is filtered, if you use rng, it will still refer to the entire range including those hidden (essentially ignoring the filter). This is why you should now use rng.specialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) to now refer to the displaying range.

Mix and match filters and then use `rng.specialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next way. It uses an array and builds a `Union` range, to be copied at the code end. That's why is should be much faster than iterating between all cells and copying a row at a time:

```
Sub DataValidation()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, rngCopy As Range, i As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    arr = ws.Range("AU4:AV" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration/processing

    For i = 2 To UBound(arr) '2 supposing that headers exist on the first row
        If (arr(i, 1) <> "" And arr(i, 2) = "") Or (arr(i, 2) <> "" And arr(i, 1) = "") Then
            addToRange rngCopy, ws.Range("A" & i)
        End If
    Next i
        
   If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.EntireRow.Copy _
         Sheets("test").Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End Sub

Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this! What if my headers on my filtered sheet is on row 3?

Comment: ive updated my code in the question. Im not getting any results on my test tab. Any inkling as to why?

Comment: @Jonnyboi You should start the iteration from 4 (instead of 2). Is the sheet to be processed the active one? Is there anything in A:A column? Try running the code line by line, pressing `F8` and move the cursor over each involved variable. Is `LastR` correct (the last row of A:A column)?

Comment: @Jonnyboi  You missed copying of the necessary `addToRange` `Sub`... Do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk application installed? If so and you accept a connection I will see what's happening on your workbook... I tested my code and it works as it should. Don't you need copying the rows having empty cell in A:A a  non empty in B:B, or viceversa?

Comment: so Col A should be used to get last row. But Im actually wanting to check rows AU4:AV Last Row. Headers start at row 3.   I am running the code on the activesheet. LastR is correct.  A:A column does have values but should only be used for LastR.  I didnt make any change to the `addtorange` function.   Yes I need to copy the rows have empty in AU:AU AND non empty in AV:AV or vice versa. It seems like nothign is copying over. I have put a test value in AU4 , and left AV4 blank. nothing copies.

Comment: @Jonnyboi  Then, of course, it cannot work... Why didn't you say which is the range to be used? I will adapt the answer to work on the range you mention now... Adapted! Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Okay so it works as is but the header part is not accurate. I get the data above headers and the code or loop stops.  Ie if my row 2 is some other information i have, it copies that to test tab. and stops at row 2. I want to go to row 4 and loop all the way down and copy those rows. However headers are on row 3 in my sheet. But when I adjust `i=2` to `i=4` i do not get anything copied over to test.

Comment: upon further testing, it seems to be working after changes `i=4` however the code is ending after row 4 . I think its not looping through all rows. Ie only row 4 is being copied to my test tab.

Comment: okay i moved the copy to test part inside the the loop. And... it copies row 4 repeatedly It needs to copy the other rows not just row 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249202/discussion-between-faneduru-and-jonnyboi).

Comment: Whay do hou play with code and do not use the adapted code exactly as it is? Only check if the same number of rows in A:A column. I am driving..

Comment: Refresh the page, please.

Comment: I posted my new code. It seems to only populate the row 4 to my test sheet. It should populate more rows then just hte one. I have test values throughout AU and AV.

Comment: @Jonnyboi This only means that you do not have data in "A:A" column, as you said. In such a situation, using `lastR = ws.Range("AU" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row` should cover such a scenario...